# What do roses stand for in "The Nightingale and the Rose" by Oscar Wilde?

Tags: short-stories, symbolism, oscar-wilde

There are 3 times roses appear in the garden ["The Nightingale and the Rose"](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/NigRos.shtml) by Oscar Wilde:

1. White rose: Marriage / chastity / young love / loyalty
2. Yellow rose: Betrayal / sadness / doubt
3. Red rose: True love / passion

What does it mean when a rose appears? I know for a time he worked for women's world magazine as editor-in-chief. Did this affect him when he wrote "The Nightingale and the Rose"?

Comment: Can you identify the source of the attributes you have listed for various colours of rose and your purpose in including them here?